# Python/Selenium how to find a div that contains parts of a text from a variable?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am scraping telegram, I have the usernames saved in a variable labelled, `clone` and the `span` class that contains the username is labelled `peer-title`. The code that I have written below works in most instances but crashes if there is a special character/emoji in the username.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='peer-title' and text() = '"+clone[0]+"']")
```

If there is an emoji or special character then it's no longer able to find the specified element/username. I believe it's because it's looking for an exact text match and isn't able to save the special characters/emojis into the list variable.

Is there any way around this, for example by changing the code above to seek parts of a match vs exact that it's currently doing?

Comment: Have you tried with `contains` like - `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='peer-title' and contains(text() , '"+clone[0]+"')]")`

Comment: Still run into issues, some names contain an image vs an emoiji and it doesn't handle those exceptions.  Here is a "normal" name:                                         
<span class="peer-title">Cori</span>                                                               
Here is a username that, the above cannot handle, I assume it's because it contains an image vs a character emoiji:                                                                                                                <span class="peer-title" > <img src="assets/img/1f4.png" alt="" class="emoji">SFS</span>

Comment: How does a `clone` variable look like for a name with special character or a emjoy. Better share more HTML code of the Element.

Comment: For the above example I would use clone[0] = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='peer-title']").text which would equal "Cori SFS", ignoring the emoji. However, when I try to find the element back in the page, because it cut out the emoji it's unable to find it.

Comment: Typo in above, editted/fixed.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed both.